# Problems with parse and Facebook log in

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook, parse-platform

When I run this meted the app crashes

```
    [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:@[] block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    if (!user) {
        NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
    } else if (user.isNew) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    } else {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}];
```

this is that is get on the log

```
2014-10-26 03:30:05.097 RecipesBook[2196:490585] +[PFUser _logInWithAuthTypeInBackground:]:unrecognized selector sent to class 0x383b48
```

2014-10-26 03:30:05.100 RecipesBook[2196:490585] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[PFUser _logInWithAuthTypeInBackground:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x383b48'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x252cdc1f 0x32ad5c8b 0x252d2f55 0x252d0f57 0x25202df8 0x96f0d 0x96f57 0x667ab 0x287bdc2b 0x287bdbd1 0x287a8863 0x287bd63d 0x287bd317 0x287b6be1 0x2878d3dd 0x28a00c29 0x2878be39 0x25294377 0x25293787 0x25291ded 0x251e0211 0x251e0023 0x2c5930a9 0x287ec1d1 0x38d75 0x33055aaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

the frameworks that I have (that are for parse) are 
FacebookSDK
Bolts
ParseFacebookUtils
Parse

Please help

Answer (score 0):

**Try replacing**

```
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:@[] block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error)
```

**with**

```
 [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error)
```